# Prove an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I've show span(1,x) is a suba-algebra. I'm not sure what the isomorphism from span{1,x} to the complex numbers is (sending 1 to 1, x to i doesn't work) and indeed I don't how that helps prove A is isomorphic to the quaternions.

The image isn't very clear. Basically we want to prove the set of quarternions is isomorphic to A which has basis {1,x,y,z} and multiplication given by the table. The hint say to show that span{1,x} is a subalgebra oF A and isomorphic to set of complex numbers. I don't see the link between this and finding a new basis for A with the same structure coefficents as {1,i,j,k}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B=\langle 1,x\rangle$, and define $\phi:B\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\phi(1)=1$ and $\phi(x)=1+i$. Then $\phi(x\cdot x)=\phi(x^2)=\phi(2x-2)=2(i+1)-2=2i$, and $\phi(x)\cdot \phi(x)=(1+i)(1+i)=2i$. This should help you with $B$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. Now extend the definition of $\phi$ to $j$ and $k$ in a similar manner.